# AES-128 with weak key

Tags: brute-force-attack

Doing malware research (simple crypto locker) I found out that it uses AES-128 with weak key - every one of the sixteen bytes is represented by (a-z,A-Z,0-9). Thus simple brute-force attack should iterate through $62^{16}$, that is approximately $2^{96}$ keys. I have a file before encryption and after.

Is it feasible in modern world to brute-force it to find a key with a budget of $3-4k?

Comment: Can you post the asm code or pseudocode for the key generation?

Comment: Note that the term "weak key" also has a different meaning in the cryptographic world. It may also refer to a key that is inherently weak for the specific algorithm. This key is not; it's just badly defined/generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not.

[Here](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2012/10/when_will_we_se.html), Bruce Schneier estimates the cost of finding a SHA-1 collision. He estimates that this would require approximately 2<sup>74</sup> CPU cycles and cost about \$700 thousand in 2015. Trying 2<sup>96</sup> AES keys would require approximately 2<sup>100</sup> CPU cycles and cost about \$50 trillion.

Comment: Although I am pretty sure that the calculations are approx. in the right ballpark - i.e. not feasible - , it may be a bit tricky for readers to jump from SHA-1 collisions to AES key brute forcing.